# Определить количество столбцов матрицы содержащих 0 элемент - С++

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Нужна помощь, есть код который определяет количество столбцов в матрице содержащих нулевой элемент, но он работает неправильно. Например у меня 5 столбцов содержащих 0, а результат выводит как 4 т.е. на единицу меньше, не могу понять с чем это связано

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        const long n = 10;

        int A[n][n];
        int i, j, sum = 0, k = 0;

        cout << "Ваша матрица:\n";

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                A[i][j] = rand() % 10;
                cout << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        sort(A[0], A[0] + n);
        cout << "Отсортированная первая строка двухмерного массива: ";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << A[0][i] << ' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (A[i][j] == 0)
                {
                    k++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout <<"\nКоличество столбцов содержащих 0-й элемент: " << k << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы ищете число **строк** с нулевым элементом...

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (A[j][i] == 0)
        {
            k++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

И еще - может оказаться ситуация, когда после сортировки первой строки число таких столбцов станет меньше/больше... Так что считайте **до** сортировки.